# Add new row in GridPane in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

I have an object where I store my data about file.

How can I add a new line with already filled fields (checkbox, combobox...)

[image: Testing GridPane]

Comment: Looks like you should use [`TableView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html) instead.

Comment: It is possible with both tableview and gridpane.

Answer (score 0):

```
GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
TextField textField = new TextField("Text Field");
gridPane.add(textField, 1, 1);
Label label = new Label("Label");
gridPane.add(label, 0, 1);
```

Similarly you can add any field into grid pane with its row and column index with the values too.

Comment: Ok good but when i need to add 20 rows? or 30? it cant be hardcoded when user adding new city in gui.

Comment: Then iterate it with the for loop...and generate a sequence of fxid for the fields..also increment row index and column index of grid pane